# I want to add html file in webview using firebase Database how can I add

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to add a HTML file in webview using firebase Database in the android studio. How can I add it?

My other question is: I want to make a QR code specific so that my app is only open when the QR code in the app and the picture captured by the Camera are the same. The picture on app changes daily by Firebase real-time database. People cannot see the database picture they only scan the picture lying in front of them. How to solve this?

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add HTML file in Webview, you can load  that file HTML content in Webview,
firstly you have to read that file then load its content on webview for example,  I have a URL that contains HTML data as like below images
[image]

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
                    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                            return false;
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onPageFinished(final WebView view, String url) {
                            Log.e("Fin", "page finished loading " + url);
                            float_addiItem.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            float_addiItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view1) {
                                    createWebPrintJob(view);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                    webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", response, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

Comment: Can I add pdf file?? through firebase database

Comment: No, you can not add pdf file directly in the webview , it must you have to read that file content then load that content into webview